# Drawing in canvas with react doing weird things when rotating

Tags: html, reactjs, canvas, rotation, frontend

I'm trying to draw in a canvas in a react component. The component draws a line and a number of squares depending on the length of an array passed to it as props inclining rotating all of them depending on another prop.
I have a loop that draws it perfectly until it reaches the 5th iteration, then something happens and it start to mess with the context restoration after the rotation. There is only one change of value in that loop ( initialX) Debugging the loop in the browser the rotate method is called the same times as the restore. I'm really confused by this behaviour, it is a very simple draw and I can't see where is my mistake.

[This is what I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8AHX.png)

[This is the same sketch without applying rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVLmC.png)

```js
class Sketch extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        let canvas = document.getElementById("plano");
        let detector = this.props.detector
        let X, Y;
        if (canvas && canvas.getContext && detector) {
            inicializarCanvas(detector);

            function inicializarCanvas(detector) {
                let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                let s = getComputedStyle(canvas);
                let w = s.width;
                let h = s.height;
                canvas.width = w.split("px")[0];
                canvas.height = h.split("px")[0];
                X = canvas.width / 2;
                Y = canvas.height / 2;

                //draw beam
                ctx.moveTo( canvas.width / 3, canvas.height / 2);
                ctx.lineTo(0, canvas.height / 2);
                ctx.strokeStyle = "#f00";
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.restore();
                ctx.restore();
                ctx.save();

                drawBlades(ctx, canvas.width, canvas.height, detector)
            }

         

            function drawBlades(ctx, x, y, detector) {
                let initialX = x / 3
                let initialY = y / 4
                let thick = 20
                let margin = 5
                let rotation = (90 - detector.angle) * Math.PI / 180
                let i = 0
                ctx.save();
                let canvas = document.getElementById("plano");
                let ctx2 = canvas.getContext("2d");
                ctx2.save();
                console.log("blade draw")
                
                //This loop is messing up at the 5th iteration
                for (; i < detector.blades.length; i++) {
                    ctx2.strokeStyle = "#000000";
                    ctx2.translate(initialX, initialY);
                    ctx2.rotate(rotation);
                    ctx2.strokeRect(0, 0, thick, y / 2);
                    ctx2.restore()
                    // this is the only variable in that changes of
                    // value in the loop
                    initialX = margin + thick + initialX
                }
                ctx2.save()
            }
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='sketch'>
                <canvas width="400" height="150" id="plano">
                   Canvas not compatible with your browser
                </canvas>
            </div>
        )
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're restoring your context in each iteration but you don't save it.

Try to add a `ctx2.save()` and it will work.

```
for (; i < detector.blades.length; i++) {
    ctx2.save(); // save the context
    ctx2.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    ctx2.translate(initialX, initialY);
    ctx2.rotate(rotation);
    ctx2.strokeRect(0, 0, thick, y / 2);
    ctx2.restore()
    // this is the only variable in that changes of
    // value in the loop
    initialX = margin + thick + initialX
}
```

Comment: /i knew it was something obvious. Thanks you so much

Comment: Any explanation why it was drawing the four fist squares correctly and then it wasn't?